# Why must the 'struct' keyword precede struct instances in C?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Let's say I define a struct in C. If I declare an instance of that struct, it's necessary that I include the 'struct' keyword in front of it.

```
// Define struct
struct Book {
   char title[50];
   char author[50];
   char subject[100];
   int book_id;
};

// Instantiate struct
int main()
{
    struct Book myBook;
}
```

My question: why is it necessary for the struct keyword to precede any instantiation of the struct? It seems like the compiler would have plenty of information to deduct that 'Book' is a struct.

I realize you can get around this by using a typedef, but that really just seems like boiler plate code for something the compiler should already know.

Comment: In C, structs and unions each have their own namespace distinct from the global namespace. You have to say `struct` so it knows to look in the struct namespace.

Comment: @RaymondChen: The tag namespace is shared between structs, unions, and enums - you can't have both `struct foo` and `union foo` in the same scope, for example.  Labels get their own namespace, as do `struct` and `union` members.  All other identifiers (variable names, function names, enumeration constants, etc.) are lumped into the "ordinary identifier" namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Due to using the keywords struct, union and enum names for these types can form their own namespace that will not conflict with names of other entities.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    struct Book 
    {
        const char *Book;
    } Book = { "The first favorite book" };

    struct Book otherBook = { .Book = "The second favorite book" };

    puts( Book.Book );
    puts( otherBook.Book );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Judging if this is an advantage serious enough to counterbalance the annoyance of writing `struct` all the time (or using the `typedef` trick, which historically confused debugging information) is left to the reader.

Comment: @MatteoItalia The problem is that there can be conflicts with names in other modules or libraries. Using the keywords allows to avoid these conflicts.

Comment: not really... it just keeps types into a separate namespace, which is still shared between all included libraries, so it helps just in the unlikely case of a conflict between a type and another kind of symbol. If you have conflicting function names (which is what generally happen) you are just as in trouble.

Comment: @MatteoItalia You are contradicting yourself. If you are speaking about separate namespaces then you are confirming my statement. You just do not understand what you are saying yourself.

Comment: There's a namespace for structs, a namespace for unions and a namespace for all the rest; each one of them is shared between all the libraries you include. What I'm saying is simply that it's a separation of the wrong kind - you want to have a namespace for each library, not a namespace for each kind of entities (which can still have conflicting names between different libraries).

Comment: @MatteoItalia For starters there is one namespace for tags of structures, unions and enumerations. But one more you do not understand what you are saying. Using separate namespaces allows to decrease name conflicts. That is all.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Moreover in my answer I showed a demonstrative program where the same one name is used in three different name spaces.

Comment: I don't know why you get all this worked up; the fact that there are those separate namespaces is clear, and is clear as well that names in different namespaces don't conflict. All I'm saying is that it's a weak solution for the "name conflicts between unrelated libraries", because it only separates for type of entity, not for "library of origin", so it helps you only if the name conflicts you have are between different kind of entity, which, in my experience, happens quite rarely (99% of name conflicts I ever had were about function names).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Nobody says that this resolves all problems with the name collision. But this allows to decrease name collisions.

Answer (score 0):

With the current arrangement, you could have both `struct Book` and a global/local symbol named `Book`, which doesn't need to be related to `struct Book`. `struct stat` existing alongside a function named `stat` is a nice example this feature being used in POSIX.

Clearly, you could automate the typedefing as C++ has done (and thereby lose the possibility of having a perhaps unrelated `Book` and `struct Book` in the same scope), but I guess that not automating it makes the grammar perhaps neater, because then if you don't use `typedef`s at all, you've got a basically context-free grammar, whereas with `typedef`s (explicit or implicit) a context of currently valid `typedef`ed types has to be maintained by the parser.

---

Personally, I prefer automated `typedef`ing to the possibility of having a global scope coexist with a struct tag of the same name, and so I do:

```
#define Struct(Nm,...) typedef struct Nm Nm; struct Nm __VA_ARGS__
#define Union(Nm,...) typedef union Nm Nm; union Nm __VA_ARGS__
#define Enum(Nm,...) enum Nm __VA_ARGS__; typedef enum Nm Nm

Struct(Book,{
   char title[50];
   char author[50];
   char subject[100];
   int book_id;
});
```

(You may want to use it alongside a naming convention that lets you know you're dealing with a struct/union/enum (e.g., `_s` as in `book_s`)).