# Defining a new instance of a struct

Tags: c, object, struct

I tried typing the following code in a simple C project, but it keeps saying that MyStruct is undefined – unless I add `struct` before every `MyStruct` (i.e. `struct MyStruct my_struct;` which just feels wrong?).

```
struct MyStruct {
    int my_int;
}

int main() {
    MyStruct my_struct;
    my_struct->my_int = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39839000/635608

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555734/why-must-the-struct-keyword-precede-struct-instances-in-c?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not wrong, it’s the way C works. Type name is `struct MyStruct` (it would be simply `MyStruct` in C++). If you feel that inconvenient, make a typedef, like:

```
typedef struct MyStruct { ... } MyStruct;
```

That may or may not be considered a good practice, though.

Also note that a struct (but not a typedef) and a function can have the same name (without the `struct` prefix). `sigaction` is a real-word example of that.

Comment: Very useful! I guess I'm too used to C++. This is for a C assignment, though, so I guess getting used to writing `struct MyStruct` would be better practice to remind myself of how C differs from C++.